# Magento 2 - Configurable product, get attribute value from associated simple products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configurable-product

I'm looking for a way to grab the values of an attribute (let's say color) from all simple products associated with a configurable.

So if my associated simple products are:

- Simple1 - Red
- Simple2 - Blue
- Simple3 - Green

On my configurable, I'm looking for a way to output "Red, Blue, Green".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer**: Use of `ObjectManager` Directly is highly discouraged in a production environment. `Inject the dependencies` in the respective class instead.

```
<?php 
// custom script to get associated simple products with their options for a configurable product     
ini_set('display_errros',1);
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$ObjectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$configurableParentSku = 'MH07';      

$_productResourceModel = $ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product'); 
$productId = $_productResourceModel->getIdBySku($configurableParentSku);

echo 'Configurable Product Parent Id: ' . $productId . PHP_EOL; 

$_productModel = $ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository'); 
$_product = $_productModel->get($configurableParentSku);

echo 'Name: ' . $_product->getName() . PHP_EOL; 

// returns associated simple product
$assocSimpleProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);

foreach ($assocSimpleProducts as $_assocSimpleProduct) {
    echo 'Sku: ' . $_assocSimpleProduct->getSku() . PHP_EOL; 
}

// returns associated simple product options

$assocSimpleProductsOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableOptions($_product);

echo '$assocSimpleProductsOptions: ' . print_r($assocSimpleProductsOptions,true) . PHP_EOL; 

// returns used options and values of a given configurable product
$productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);

echo '$productAttributeOptions: ' . print_r($productAttributeOptions,true) . PHP_EOL; 

$attributeOptions = array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}

echo '$attributeOptions: ' . print_r($attributeOptions,true) . PHP_EOL;
```